# get Unicode value [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, unicode

If you see this [link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&number=1024&htmlent=1&view=2)

Its all about unicode code range

example :

```
U+0644  ل   d9 84   ARABIC LETTER LAM
```

In PostgreSQL its easy to get hex value :

```
select encode('ل','hex')
```

it will return the hex value, d9 84.

but how to get the unicode code point ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string is in UTF-8, you can use the [ascii](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function:

> ascii(string) int
>
> ASCII code of the first character of the argument.
>   **For UTF8 returns the Unicode code point of the character**. For other
>   multibyte encodings. the argument must be a strictly ASCII character.

Comment: I tried select ascii('ل')::int
but the result is '1604', not 644. Thanks

Comment: `1604` is the decimal representation of the hexadecimal value `0x644` - if you want the hexadecimal value, run `to_hex(ascii('ل'))`.

Comment: Hi Andres
i have new problem using running this query select decode(to_hex(ascii('ل')::int),'hex'); i got error "ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits"

Comment: Hmm, why would you want to do that? It seems backwards, as you already have a character?

Comment: @Thessa, if you want to reverse the process, you can use `chr()`, e.g. `chr(1604)` will give `'ل'`